# rosrun rqt_graph rqt_graph shows error

Tags: ros, rqt-graph

[image: Rosanswers logo]

http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/UnderstandingTopics

Environment：
ROS kinetic
Ubuntu 16.04

ERROR：
rosrun rqt_graph rqt_graph

Could not import "pyqt" bindings of qt_gui_cpp library - so C++ plugins will not be available:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/qt_gui_cpp/cpp_binding_helper.py", line 43, in 
import libqt_gui_cpp_sip
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'libqt_gui_cpp_sip'

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/rqt_graph/rqt_graph", line 8, in 
sys.exit(main.main(sys.argv, standalone='rqt_graph.ros_graph.RosGraph'))
File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rqt_gui/main.py", line 59, in main
return super(Main, self).main(argv, standalone=standalone, plugin_argument_provider=plugin_argument_provider, plugin_manager_settings_prefix=str(hash(os.environ['ROS_PACKAGE_PATH'])))
File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/qt_gui/main.py", line 505, in main
plugin = plugins.keys()[0]

TypeError: 'dict_keys' object does not support indexing!

Could someone please tell me what exactly is going wrong here ? Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/255218/rosrun-rqt_graph-rqt_graph-shows-error/) by [Kfi](https://answers.ros.org/users/29433/kfi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2017-02-21

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [steven](https://answers.ros.org/users/30025/steven/) on 2017-04-14**:
Exact same problem, please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can use an alias in ubuntu

just edit the     "~/.bashrc"  or the "~/.bash_aliases" file and add: ***alias python3=python***

Test it:

```
$ python --version
Python 2.7.12
$ python3 --version
Python 3.5.2
```

enjoy!

---

Originally posted by [ΦXocę 웃 Пepeúpa ツ](https://answers.ros.org/users/29728/%CF%86xoc%C4%99-%EC%9B%83-%D0%BFepe%C3%BApa-%E3%83%84/) with karma: 424 on 2017-04-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1